# Measure Rate Of Convergence For Quadrature Methods

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

[image: Graph1]

Hi.

I'm trying to measure the rate of convergence of trap/midpoint/simpson rule for approximating the integral of (x+1261/1500)^4 between 0 and 5.

From this graph, how would I measure the rate of convergence of each method?

I am using R to produce these graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Approximate these lines per linear regression to the form
$$
\log({\rm error})=c-p\log(N)
$$
then $p$ resp. the closest integer is the order of the method.

You could also try to directly read $p$ off of the slopes in the log-lg-graph.

Comment: Thank you so much I will let you know how I get on :)